# Is there a way to change WP_DEBUG Constant from a plugin or Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

Is there a way to turn on or off WP_DEBUG from a plugin or theme without modifying the config-ini.php file in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You can activate or deactivate `WP_DEBUG` in the WordPress installation by editing the below code in `wp-config.php` file in the WordPress root directory.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

You can change the parameter to true or false as you want.

Comment: My question is if someone has defined WP_DEBUG already how do you change it in a plugin or a theme

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that `WP_DEBUG` is constant and therefore you cannot change it. But, also important, it is just a flag used by `wp_debug_mode()` which is executed in Wordpress Core, so before the theme and plugins code. What this function does is simply change some PHP directives with `ini_set()` and `error_reporting()`. So while you can't override `WP_DEBUG`, you can certainly change the same PHP directives after `wp_debug_mode()` is executed, in your theme or plugin.
The following script simply emulates the behavior of `wp_debug_mode()` with some checks.

```
function set_debug_mode($my_wp_debug, $file_name = 'debug')
{
    // $my_wp_debug is the boolean which overrides WP_DEBUG
    // $file_name is the path to the log file, relative to wp-config folder, written without file extension

    if ($my_wp_debug && !WP_DEBUG) {
        // Turn on debug
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        ini_set('display_errors', 0);

        $file_name = $file_name ? $file_name : 'debug';
        $log_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/' . $file_name .'.log';


        ini_set('log_errors', 1);
        ini_set('error_log', $log_path);

    } elseif (!$my_wp_debug && WP_DEBUG) {
        // Turn off debug

        // At this point,you may want to delete your log file.
        // If yes, uncomment the following three lines
        // $log_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/' . $file_name .'.log';
        // if (file_exists($log_path)) {
        //    unlink($log_path);
        // }
        error_reporting(E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR);
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        ini_set('log_errors', 0);
        ini_set('error_log', '');
    }
}
```

You can call `set_debug_mode()` at some point in your theme or plugin execution using a hook. For example, with `init`:

```
add_action('init', function() {
   // Turn debug on
   set_debug_mode(true);
   // Turn debug off
   //set_debug_mode(false);
});
```